# How can I implement insert_batch active record in codeigniter in inserting multiple values?

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, model, controller

I am currently working on adding multiple requests in single click using CodeIgniters insert_batch.

**This is my model**

```
function add_request($data) {
            $this->db->insert_batch('requests',$data);
        }
```

**This is my controller**
if($_POST) {

```
        $code = $this->input->post('code');
        $about = $this->input->post('about');
        $qnty = $this->input->post('quantity');
        $budget = $this->input->post('budget');
        $sched = $this->input->post('sched');

        for($i = 0; $i < count($code); $i++) {
                $data[$i] = array(
                    'code' => $code,
                    'description' => $_POST['desc'],
                    'qnty' => $qnty,
                    'budget' => $budget,
                    'sched' => $sched,
                    'from' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
                    'status' => 'Pending',
                    'about' => $about
                );
            $this->request->add_request($data[$i]);
        }
```

> This code doesnt work It only adds blank record.

Comment: By "This code doesn't work." you have to explain, what isn't working? what is it doing that it shouldn't? and what is it not doing that it should? Are there any errors? if yes, what is the error message? Eventually see this page http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve as it will surely help you.

Comment: It adds blank spaces in DB.

Comment: Blank records, either mean that the variables have no value, or that the type is incorrect... but since you don't provide the relevant code, I cannot help you further.

Comment: You need to pass array of array as $data in insert_batch. so, instead of calling the model inside Loop, just call it after Loop complete and pass $data to it. It will definitely work

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code for the controller:

```
$data = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($code); $i++) {//build the array
            $data[$i] = array(
                'code' => $code,
                'description' => $_POST['desc'],
                'qnty' => $qnty,
                'budget' => $budget,
                'sched' => $sched,
                'from' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
                'status' => 'Pending',
                'about' => $about
            );

    }
//$data will be a bidimentional array
//pass $data to the model after the looping is done, thus the array is complete
$this->request->add_request($data);
```